# How to copy python object to arbitrary depth?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to copy a python object to an arbitrary depth. for example

`copy.deepcopy(my_object, 3)` would deep copy `my_object` to a depth of three and then shallow copy anything deeper than 3.

Is there some python functions that already exists that can do this? If not what what is the most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: I don't know of anything builtin to do that.  Also, how to do it will depend on what `my_object` is.

Comment: I just check the doc of [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) and didn't find a 'depth' parameter. Did I miss anything?

Comment: There may be some utility in the inspect module or dir function. Otherwise, I'm not sure. In the end, this is a finite recursive descent problem, yes?

Answer (score -2):

According to the documentation (and my testing) `copy.deepcopy` does NOT take an extra argument (well it does, but not the depth), `copy.deepcopy(my_object, 3)` results in `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'` (since it expect a `memo` object here instead).

On the other hand `copy.deepcopy` does not require an additional argument. You could just call `copy.deepcopy(my_object)` and it will copy with indefinite depth.

There are some catcha's you could run into that makes the copy misbehave. Basically you could end up copying too much or too little depending on whether the objects has proper support for deep copies.

Comment: Yes I already know that `copy.deepcopy` does not have a depth argument. The "catchas" that you mentioned are my problem and that is why I want to specify a depth.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your your question. As there's no way to do this without running into other corner cases (classes that implement `__deepcopy__` for example) I think you have to be specific about your needs.